# Create region/limits for NMinimize from list

Tags: replacement, regions

`NMinimize` can accept a region to optimize over. I'm looking to create an expression that represents a region from a list of limits e.g.

```
limits = {{500, 5000}, {1000, 4000}, {1000, 10000}, {1000, 50000}};
```

Output:

```
{500<t[1]<5000 && 1000<t[2]< 4000 && 1000<t[3]<10000 && 1000<t[4]<500000}
```

However, I can't do it from the list, this is the best I can do

```
variables = Table[t[i], {i, Length[taus]}];
limits = {{500, 5000}, {1000, 4000}, {1000, 10000}, {1000, 50000}};

limits = Flatten[
  Table[{limits[[i, 1]] < variables[[i]] < limits[[i, 2]] "&&"}, {i, 
    1, Length[variables], 1}]]

(* Output is wrong: {500 < t[1] < 5000 "&&", 1000 < t[2] < 4000 "&&", 
 1000 < t[3] < 10000 "&&", 1000 < t[4] < 50000 "&&"} *)
```

Comment: `NMinimize[f, Array[t, Length@limits] \[Element] Cuboid @@ Transpose@limits]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
limits = {{500, 5000}, {1000, 4000}, {1000, 10000}, {1000, 50000}};
ClearAll[f]
f[{min_, max_}, {pos_}] := min < t[pos] < max
And @@ MapIndexed[f, limits]

(* Out: 500 < t[1] < 5000 && 1000 < t[2] < 4000 && 1000 < t[3] < 10000 && 1000 < t[4] < 50000 *)
```

Note that the output format is slightly different from what you asked. It seems to me that it would be better to *either* have a list of conditions, *or* conditions joined by `And`, but not both. If you do actually need a single-element list of the conditions joined by And, then change the last line to `List[And @@ MapIndexed[f, limits]]`.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `Thread`.

```
limits = {{500, 5000}, {1000, 4000}, {1000, 10000}, {1000, 50000}};
variables = Array[t, Length@limits];
NMinimize[{Norm[variables], 
  Thread[First /@ limits < variables < Last /@ limits]}, variables]
```

> `{1802.78, {t[1] -> 500.001, t[2] -> 1000., t[3] -> 1000.,  t[4] -> 1000.}}`

Or

```
limits = {{500, 5000}, {1000, 4000}, {1000, 10000}, {1000, 50000}};
variables = Array[t, Length@limits];
NMinimize[{Norm[variables], 
  Thread[limits[[All, 1]] < variables < limits[[All, 2]]]}, variables]
```

> `{1802.78, {t[1] -> 500.001, t[2] -> 1000., t[3] -> 1000.,  t[4] -> 1000.}}`

Or

```
limits = {{500, 5000}, {1000, 4000}, {1000, 10000}, {1000, 50000}};
variables = Array[t, Length@limits];
NMinimize[{Norm[variables], 
  Thread[variables ∈ Interval /@ limits]}, variables]
```

> `{1802.78, {t[1] -> 500.001, t[2] -> 1000., t[3] -> 1000.,  t[4] -> 1000.}}`

Comment: `Thread[Thread[limits][[1]] < variables < Thread[limits][[2]]]`

Answer (score 1):

```
constraint = Thread @* Between;

constraint [Array[t, Length @ limits], limits]
```

> ```
> {500 <= t[1] && t[1] <= 5000, 
>  1000 <= t[2] && t[2] <= 4000, 
>  1000 <= t[3] && t[3] <= 10000,
>  1000 <= t[4] && t[4] <= 50000}
> ```

```
 Simplify @ %
```

> ```
> {500 <= t[1] <= 5000,
>  1000 <= t[2] <= 4000, 
>  1000 <= t[3] <= 10000, 
>  1000 <= t[4] <= 50000}
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Let us call the function you want to minimize `f[x]`. For a simple example I choose `f[x_]=x^2`. With this:

```
f[x_] = x^2;
limits = {{500, 5000}, {1000, 4000}, {1000, 10000}, {1000, 50000}};
NMinimize[{f[x], #[[1]] < x < #[[2]]}, x] & /@ limits

(* {{250000., {x -> 500.}}, {1.*10^6, {x -> 1000.}}, {1.*10^6, {x -> 
    1000.}}, {1.*10^6, {x -> 1000.}}}*)
```

Comment: I don't think this is what OP had in mind. They have a function of four variables, not a function of one variable over different ranges.